# Printing Infopath form 2010(.xml) in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint

My question is related to printing an Infopath 2010 form in Sharepoint 2010.I designed an Infopath 2010 form in Infopath Designer 2010 and published it to a form library in Sharepoint 2010.The end user fill the form and store it in .xml format in the document library.Now I would like to print the form filled by the end user? Any Ideas or suggestion about the above scenario?Please consider both browser based forms and normal forms

Comment: This should be asked on [StackOverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Not a programming question - voted to close.

Answer (score 0):

By default InfoPath will just print and work but you might want to format things differently.

Create a new view then craft it the way you want. For print views, you might want to create controls that show the data in label format rather than text boxes and display things like Yes/No fields as text. It will take some work but you can build out a view that's customized for print media.

Once you've created the view select the Page Design tab and under properties for that view click on the Print Settings. From there you can set the default print view, what the headers/footers are, etc.